# How to use paste with for-loops?

Tags: r, loops, stringi

I am trying to use the function *stri_join*, from the library *stringi* in a loop, but I am having difficulties. I would like to obtain "A_1.png", "A_2.png", "A_3.png", "A_4.png", "A_5.png", and so on until "A_200.png".

Here is my attempt:

```
 x <- c(1:200)
 x
 for (i in 1:length(x)){
   Names <-paste("A_", 1:length(i), ".png",sep = "")
   print(Names)
 }
```

I obtain "A_1.png" 200 times. If you could point what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a loop for this as `paste` is vectorized.  So either use `sprintf`

```
Names <- sprintf("A_%d.png", x)
```

Or `paste`

```
Names <- paste0("A_", x, ".png")
```

---

If this is an exercise on `for` loop, initialize the 'Names' vector and assign each element of 'Names' to the corresponding value from `paste`

```
Names <- character(length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)){
  Names[i] <- paste0("A_", i, ".png") 
}
```

Comment: please can you give me a hint on how to attach the indices values in the out put if you have two for loops in r?       res <- c()
for (i in seq(1, 21, 2)) {
  for (j in seq(22, 30)) { model, how to attach the values of i and j in the output res <- c(res, model).. thanks!

Comment: @Stackuser I would return as a `list` if i understand your question

Comment: thanks! I just want to attach the indices value in the result like if i and j are equal to 1, I want to get like 1-1-output(number or anything), then 1-2-output, 1-3-output.......

Answer (score 1):

`stringi` solution:

```
stri_paste("A_",1:200,".png")
```

Paste 'A_' with a vector from 1 to 200 and '.png'. Vectorization comes to help and we get the desired result.

Comment: What is the difference between `paste0` and `stringi::stri_paste`?